# How to store multiple distinct Python Tkinter OptionMenu selections

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, optionmenu

Ive created a function that creates and packs some drop down menus. the only issue Im now facing is figuring out how to store the selection from all 6 menus into a list? im able to access the menus selection through the func() method, but im stuck as how to store all these?  ideally id like to have all 6 selections stored in a list, is this possible?

```
def func(value):
     x = value
     print(value)


def GetEntry(x):
    var = StringVar()    
    var.set('select one')    
    formatted = x.get().split()##gets the entry and forms a list
    getMeal = CsvLoadSearch(u, formatted)
    meal = OptionMenu(root, var, *getMeal, command = func ).pack()        

mealOneButton = Button(root, text = "query database", command = lambda : GetEntry(mealOneString)) 
mealTwoButton = Button(root, text = "query database", command = lambda : GetEntry(mealTwoString))
mealThreeButton = Button(root, text = "query database", command = lambda : GetEntry(mealThreeString))
mealFourButton = Button(root, text = "query database", command = lambda : GetEntry(mealFourString))
mealFiveButton = Button(root, text = "query database", command = lambda : GetEntry(mealFiveString))
mealSixButton = Button(root, text = "query database", command = lambda : GetEntry(mealSixString))
```

this is the program bellow:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import csv
import os

u = "C:\\Users\\luke daniels\\Documents\\fooddata.csv"

"""
   Loads csv and compares elements from foodList with current row.
   returns a list of rows that match elements in foodList.
"""
def CsvLoadSearch(u, foodList):
    results = []

    inputfile = open(u)            
    for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
        for food in foodList:
            if food in row[0]:
                results.append(row)
                ##print(row)
    return results

##gets selection from drop down
def func(value):
    x = value   

def GetEntry(x):
    var = StringVar()    
    var.set('select one')    
    formatted = x.get().split()##gets the entry and forms a list
    getMeal = CsvLoadSearch(u, formatted)
    meal = OptionMenu(root, var, *getMeal, command = func ).pack()



root = Tk()
root.title("MacroCalc")    

caloriesAim = StringVar()
protien = StringVar()
fat = StringVar()
carbs = StringVar()    

mealOneString = StringVar()
mealTwoString = StringVar()
mealThreeString = StringVar()
mealFourString = StringVar()
mealFiveString = StringVar()
mealSixString = StringVar()

mealOneKeyword = Entry(root, textvariable = mealOneString)
mealTwoKeyword = Entry(root, textvariable = mealTwoString)
mealThreeKeyword = Entry(root, textvariable = mealThreeString)
mealFourKeyword = Entry(root, textvariable = mealFourString)
mealFiveKeyword = Entry(root, textvariable = mealFiveString)
mealSixKeyword = Entry(root, textvariable = mealSixString)

mealLabel = Label(root,text = "meals")
mealLabel.config(font=("Courier", 30))
mealLabel.pack()
mealLone = Label(root,text = "meal one") 
mealLtwo = Label(root,text = "meal two")
mealLthree = Label(root,text = "meal three")
mealLfour = Label(root,text = "meal four")
mealLfive = Label(root,text = "meal five")
mealLsix = Label(root,text = "meal six")    

caloriesLabel = Label(root,text = "calories needed").pack()
calories = Text(root, height = 1, width = 10).pack()
protienLabel= Label(root,text = "protien ratio").pack()
protien = Text(root, height = 1, width = 4).pack()
carbsLabel = Label(root,text = "carbohydrate ratio").pack()
carbs = Text(root, height = 1, width = 4).pack()
fatsLabel = Label(root,text = "fats ratio").pack()
fats = Text(root, height = 1, width = 4).pack()

displayText = Text(root).pack(side = RIGHT)    

mealOneButton = Button(root, text = "query database", command = lambda : GetEntry(mealOneString)) 
mealTwoButton = Button(root, text = "query database", command = lambda : GetEntry(mealTwoString))
mealThreeButton = Button(root, text = "query database", command = lambda : GetEntry(mealThreeString))
mealFourButton = Button(root, text = "query database", command = lambda : GetEntry(mealFourString))
mealFiveButton = Button(root, text = "query database", command = lambda : GetEntry(mealFiveString))
mealSixButton = Button(root, text = "query database", command = lambda : GetEntry(mealSixString))    

mealButtons = [mealOneButton, mealTwoButton, mealThreeButton, mealFourButton, mealFiveButton, mealSixButton]
mealKeywords = [mealOneKeyword, mealTwoKeyword, mealThreeKeyword, mealFourKeyword, mealFiveKeyword, mealSixKeyword]
mealLabels = [mealLone, mealLtwo, mealLthree, mealLfour, mealLfive, mealLsix]


##packs the drop downs and respective lables
i = 0
while i < len(mealLabels):
    mealLabels[i].pack()
    mealKeywords[i].pack()
    mealButtons[i].pack()
    ##meal.pack()
    i = i + 1      

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Pass in a list of all 6 of them instead of 6 different ones.

Comment: @StevenSummers would it be any trouble to show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: @StevenSummers oh wait i think i get what you mean. unfortunately i need the 6 different drop downs so thats not an option.

Comment: @StevenSummers cheers mate, that would help me a lot.

Comment: Actually, could you provide a better/working example? Because I don't quite follow what your buttons are meant to do. It seems you are creating the OptionMenus on button click instead of processing their values. What is `mealNString`?

Comment: @StevenSummers the buttons do create the OptionMenus on click but before they create the option menu they take user input from an Entry which is then processed by CsvLoadSearch() which returns a list. ill post the program if that helps. its not very big.

Comment: It would be best to look into using classes to manage your application and make it more dynamic. Additionally with lines like `b = Button(...).pack()`, `pack` returns `None` so `b` is `None` and not a `Button`. You also don't need a `StringVar` for an `Entry` widget.

Comment: @StevenSummers cheers ill look into it!